# I need to sum all the data entered to a variable

Tags: javascript

hello i needed help but now i do not

Comment: The user can only select one type. So you either set `C` or `D`, but not both.

Comment: Is this supposed to be in a loop?

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the loop, the variables will only contain the last value that the user entered for each type. If you want to add all the numbers, you should update the total during the loop, not afterward.

Also, you should use `parseInt()` to convert the input to a number. Otherwise it will do string concatenation instead of addition.

```js
var total = 0;
do {
  var type = prompt("Enter the type")

  if (type === "C") {
    var C = prompt("Enter the quantity")
    total += parseInt(C);
  }

  if (type === "D") {
    var D = prompt("Enter the quantity")
    total += parseInt(D);
  }
} while (type !== "E")
console.log(total);
```